# Где можно скачать бесплатные SCORM упаковщики?

Tags: html

Доброго времени суток. Не подскажете, где можно скачать бесплатные SCORM упаковщики?

Comment: Задача своеобразная. Могу предположить, что в чистом виде вы такого и не найдете - оно может входить в комплект самих дистанционных систем, а они бесплатными не будут никогда. Если нужно что-то маленькое, найдите готовый пакет и доколупайте блокнотом или FAR'ом до нужного вида. Оно все как бы XML-based.

Comment: Да мне просто руководитель сказал,что нужно найти бесплатные "их куча". Ну вот что-то как-то не находится :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А разве в гугле поиск по "SCORM Packager" не выдает ничего полезного?  например что-то подобное [building scorm packager tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982588/building-scorm-packager-tool)